# react-virtualized Grid.cellRenderer - issues adding style prop

Tags: grid, react-virtualized, cellrenderer

I am using the Grid component and have a cellRenderer. In it I attempt to add a backgroundColor style to the outer div.

```
customColumnRenderer(props: GridCellProps): React.ReactNode {  
    ...
      props.style.backgroundColor = "hotpink";
    ...
      return <div style={props.style} 
    ... </div>;   
}
```

All is good at first, but then I scroll vertically a bit and I get this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'backgroundColor' of object '#<Object>'
```

When I look in the debugger. props.style looks like a simple Object to me. The doc says 
"You can add additional class names or style properties as you would like."

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Best workaround I could come up with is to merge in style props from a different object using the spread operator. Something like this:

```
customColumnRenderer(props: GridCellProps): React.ReactNode {  
    ...
      let myStyles = {backgroundColor: "hotpink"};
      let styles = {...props.style, ...myStyles};
    ...
      return <div style={styles} 
    ... </div>;   
}
```

Comment: This is the way I suggest doing it.